# What does exactly the warning mean about hidden symbol being referenced by DSO?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, elf

I have a problem linking some shared library with g++. It gives me a warning like:

```
hidden symbol XXX in YYY is referenced by DSO /usr/lib/...
```

I've read some related questions about particular problems, but I want to understand it in a whole - what does this warning mean and what is a cause:

1. What is DSO?
2. What is a hidden symbol?
3. How can it be referenced, if it's hidden?

Comment: DSO = dynamic shared object

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**What is a DSO?**

A *DSO* is a *Dynamic Shared Object*, or less formally a [*shared library*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries).

**What is a hidden symbol?**

A *hidden symbol* is a symbol (i.e. name of function or data object) that
has been compiled with *hidden linkage*, e.g. as per the (GCC specific) 
declaration:

```
int x __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")));
```

If `x` is defined in one DSO then dynamic linkage cannot reference it from a 
different DSO. The linker can see `x` (it is not `static`), but it is not
available for *dynamic* linkage. Documentation [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)

**How can it be referenced, if it's hidden?**

It can't be, which is what you are being warned about. E.g. the linktime warning:

> hidden symbol `stat' in /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(stat.oS) is referenced by DSO

is telling you that a DSO in the linkage references the symbol `stat`, and
the linker can locate a definition of `stat` in `/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a`, 
but (obviously) that definition is not in the DSO that references it
and cannot be referenced from that DSO, because it is hidden.

You get this problem if the problem DSO has not been built correctly for use
as a DSO. See [this example](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2004-01/msg00326.html)
and follow the follow-ups for the solution.

**Continued for OP's followups**

> If hidden symbol is already referenced by some DSO, then why the problem is with DSO?

The linker is saying:

The DSO `X` contains a reference to symbol `S`. I can find a definition of symbol `S` is another linked module `Y`,
but that definition will not be available to satisfy the reference in `X` *dynamically* (i.e. *at runtime*) because `S` has hidden linkage in `Y`.

> I can confirm that the problem comes with a non-shared object [...][but] I don't explicitly hide those symbols in my non-shared object.

You may not have explicitly marked any symbols hidden in the non-shared object. Depending on how it was built, symbols
may be hidden by default unless explicitly marked *otherwise*.

Say the non-shared object is `libnonshared.a` and the allegedly hidden symbol is `foo`. Run:

```
objdump -t libnonshared.a
```

to get info about the symbols in `libnonshared.a`. In the output, look for the entry for `foo`. Does it contain the tag `.hidden`? - e.g.

```
0000000000000000 g     F .text  000000000000000b .hidden foo
```

This entry says that `foo` is a global symbol (marked `g` - that's why the linker is able to see it) *but* it's hidden for *dynamic* linkage.

If this turns out to be the case then you need to go and fix the build of `libnonshared.a` so that it doesn't hide `foo`.
If not, then I'm stumped.

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your answer. If hidden symbol is already referenced by some DSO, then why the problem is with DSO? - Actually, I can confirm that the problem comes with a non-shared object, which defines some symbols possibly with a same name, that the DSO knows as external ones - they are provided in another place. Also, I don't explicitly hide those symbols in my non-shared object.

Comment: It helps, but I still having troubles to understands if, in all these hypothetical examples, there is only one library that is shared or static, or if there are two library, one static and one dynamic... ?

Answer (score 2):

This is almost a decade later from Mike's excellent answer and I wanted to provide a shorter answer that may help others in the future:

**What's happening when this error occurs:**

1. You are linking against a dynamic library which contains a symbol that is being resolved by another library
2. This error will occur if the library resolving the symbol is static (.a)
3. Try to recreate the resolving library as a dynamic library (.so)

**A specific example where I ran into this issue:**

1. I created a dynamic library which uses some OpenCV functions and therefore had some OpenCV symbols
2. I was linking the OpenCV libraries to resolve the symbols in the dynamic library, except my OpenCV libraries were static, which caused the error described in the original post.
3. I recompiled OpenCV, this time creating the libraries as dynamic
4. I attempted recompilation of my program with my dynamic library and the newly created OpenCV dynamic libraries
5. Boom, the error no longer appeared.

Good luck!