# hidden symbol being referenced by DSO - How to solve?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I am getting hidden symbol being referenced by DSO error with custom libraries during cross-compiling for ARM processors
_

**hidden symbol `_ZN7vid3App17sendToEncEPN6cam12ICam' in CMakeFiles/nix_cam.dir/vidVis.cpp.o is referenced by DSO**

A beautiful explanation about this issue is explained @ -
[What does exactly the warning mean about hidden symbol being referenced by DSO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696585/what-does-exactly-the-warning-mean-about-hidden-symbol-being-referenced-by-dso)

When checked with objdump command with the referenced shared library it showed -
00000000         *UND*  00000000             _ZN7vid3App17sendToEncEPN6cam12ICam

Now, I am clueless about how to solve this issue.
Please help...

Comment: To get help you will need to post the failing linkage command and
the errors that follow from it, verbatim from the build output.
Add this information to the body of your question.