# Hidden symbol `__udivti3' in .../libgcc.a is referenced by DSO

Tags: c, linker-errors

I am trying to compile a simple executable using CMake and Clang on Ubuntu 18. Some code coming from a third party source and compiled as a shared library  [libtommath](https://github.com/libtom/libtommath) ends up calling the function `__udivti3` after the compiler does some code optimisations.

At link time, I have an error coming from ld saying `hidden symbol "__udivti3" in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc.a(_udivdi3.o) is referenced by DSO`

I did some research and thanks to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696585/what-does-exactly-the-warning-mean-about-hidden-symbol-being-referenced-by-dso) this effectively means that `__udivti3` is referenced by the shared library but It cannot be used from the libgcc.a as it is marked as hidden in this library.

My issue is whatever I try to fix it, the linkage always fails. I tried to link with `libgcc_s` which is located in the same directory but clang complains it cannot find it. On the other hand though, the compilation and linkage work perfectly on MacOS, with that problematic symbol still being present.

Comment: I think you should be linking using *gcc* not *clang*!

Comment: I tried with gcc too and I get the same issue @AnttiHaapala